# How to remove port number from custom 'redirect-https' middleware redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy

I use node.js, express.js, greenlock-express, redirect-https and apache2.

The server uses apache2 with two vhosts on port 80.

Vhost1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia Full
  <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:3002/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:3002

</VirtualHost>
```

Vhost2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia Full
  <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://subdomain.example.com:3005/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://subdomain.example.com:3005
</VirtualHost>
```

I have two node.js apps, #1 which runs on port `3002`, and #2 which runs on port `3005`.

I have `greenlock-express` setup for each node app, with both using `redirect-https` to force a redirect to custom SSL ports.

`Node app #1` uses `httpSecureServer: 444`

`Node app #2` uses `httpSecureServer: 445`

The redirects work great, however after the redirect:

`Node app #1` 's URL stays at `https://www.example.com:444/login` after the redirect.

`Node app #2` 's URL stays at `https://subdomain.example.com:445/login` after the redirect.

Is there a graceful way for me to remove the port number from both of the redirected URLs, so:

`Node App #1` would give `https://www.example.com/login`

`Node App #2` would give `https://subdomain.example.com/login`

Is this possible?